# Streaming High Quality Camera to the same Raspberry Pi 4 - Threaded OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi, streaming, ip-camera

I am using OpenCV2 to process images streamed from a Raspberry Pi running Raspbian which is streaming using the python code from https://github.com/ogra1/picamera-streaming-demo/blob/master/pistream

I am using picamera streaming rather than OpenCV to capture the camera because the frame rate is much higher (24 FPS at 1280/720), and I can view the camera from any web browser on my network.

My threaded Python OpenCV frame capture and display code runs well on my local Windows PC, displaying with very low latency and a high frame rate. Great!

However the same code (with the local IP address or 127.0.0.1:8000) when running on the streaming Raspberry Pi doesn't capture any frames. It gets so far as to open an http connection with the local streamer, but never gets a frame to display.

The plan is run the code on the Raspberry Pi streaming to itself and process it threaded at relatively high frame rates.

The camera is a high quality camera, if that is any help.

Any thoughts on why this opens an http connection to itself and then freezes? I have tried to run it both from the command line and from a remote desktop on the pi.  I think maybe running two python programs using threads may be the issue, but how to tell?

```
from threading import Thread

import numpy as np
import cv2
import time


class VideoStreamWidget(object):
    def __init__(self, src=0):
        # Create a VideoCapture object
        self.capture = cv2.VideoCapture(src)

        # Start the thread to read frames from the video stream
        self.thread = Thread(target=self.update, args=())
        self.thread.daemon = True
        self.thread.start()

    def update(self):
        # Read the next frame from the stream in a different thread
        while True:
            if self.capture.isOpened():
                (self.status, self.frame) = self.capture.read()

    def get_frame(self):
        if self.status:
            return self.frame
        else:
            return np.empty((720,1280,3), dtype=np.uint8) # Show hasn't started yet

    def show_frame(self):
        # Display frames in main program
        if self.status:
            #self.frame = self.maintain_aspect_ratio_resize(self.frame, width=600)
            cv2.imshow('IP Camera Video Streaming', self.frame)

        # Press Q on keyboard to stop recording
        key = cv2.waitKey(1)
        if key == ord('q'):
            self.capture.release()
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()
            exit(1)

    # Resizes a image and maintains aspect ratio
    def maintain_aspect_ratio_resize(self, image, width=None, height=None, inter=cv2.INTER_AREA):
        # Grab the image size and initialize dimensions
        dim = None
        (h, w) = image.shape[:2]

        # Return original image if no need to resize
        if width is None and height is None:
            return image

        # We are resizing height if width is none
        if width is None:
            # Calculate the ratio of the height and construct the dimensions
            r = height / float(h)
            dim = (int(w * r), height)
        # We are resizing width if height is none
        else:
            # Calculate the ratio of the 0idth and construct the dimensions
            r = width / float(w)
            dim = (width, int(h * r))

        # Return the resized image
        return cv2.resize(image, dim, interpolation=inter)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    stream_link = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/stream.mjpg'
    #stream_link = 'http://192.168.1.29:8000/stream.mjpg'
    video_stream_widget = VideoStreamWidget(stream_link)
    current_frame = np.empty((720,1280,3), dtype=np.uint8)

    def similar(frame1, frame2):
        return (frame1.shape == frame2.shape and not (np.bitwise_xor(frame2, frame1).any()))

    start_time = time.time()
    frame_count = 0

    while True:
        try:
            #video_stream_widget.show_frame()
            time.sleep(.01)
            new_frame = video_stream_widget.get_frame()
            print (new_frame.shape)
            if not similar(current_frame, new_frame):
                cv2.imshow("Video Input", new_frame)
                current_frame = new_frame
                current_time = time.time()
                seconds = current_time - start_time
                frame_count += 1
                if seconds > 0:
                    fps = frame_count / seconds
                else:
                    fps = 0
                print("FPS: {}".format(fps))
                key = cv2.waitKey(1)
                if key == ord('q'):
                    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
                    exit(1)
        except AttributeError:
            pass
```